# Defaulting to integer despite float function

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to create a simple tower defense game and in the process of creating bullets fired by the tower I referenced my 8th grade knowledge of linear functions. So I assigned the variable slope (self.slope on line 29) the difference between the mouse pointer y and the y location of the tower over those same x locations. After rewriting the program entirely, and attempting to debug it in several different manners I finally came to the realization that the slope was a float while the variable was assigning it an integer. Thinking it was a simple fix I added the simple 'float()' function. This was to no avail. Please if there is any way to fix this please tell me... I am rather lost at this point.

```
import pygame, math
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
dead = False
def rot_center(image, rect, angle):
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
        rot_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
        return rot_image,rot_rect
class c_tower:
        class body:
                def __init__(self, x, y):
                        self.image=pygame.image.load('base.png')
                        self.x=x
                        self.y=y
                def update(self):
                        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        class gun:
                def __init__(self, x, y):
                        self.image=pygame.image.load('gun.png')
                        self.x=x
                        self.y=y
                def update(self):
                        self.rotated = rot_center(self.image, self.image.get_rect(), 90+(57.29*math.atan2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]-(self.x+140),pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]-(self.y+140))))
                        screen.blit(self.rotated[0],(self.rotated[1][0]+self.x,self.rotated[1][1]+self.y))
        class bullet:
                def __init__(self, x, y):
                        self.image=pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
                        print '(',y,'-',pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1],')/(',x,'-',pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],')'
                        self.slope=float((y-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])/(x-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]))
                        print float((y-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])/(x-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]))
                        print self.slope
                        self.x=x
                        self.y=y
                def update(self):
                        self.y = self.slope*self.x
                        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
                        self.x+=self.slope/abs(self.slope)
        def __init__(self,x,y):
                self.x=x
                self.y=y
                self.b=c_tower.body(x+90,y+90)
                self.g=c_tower.gun(x,y)
                self.bullets=[]
        def update(self):
                self.b.update()
                self.g.update()
                for bullet in self.bullets:
                        bullet.update()
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]==1:
                        self.bullets.append(self.bullet(self.x,self.y))


tower = c_tower(200,200)
while not dead:
        pygame.event.get()
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        tower.update()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.slope=(y-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]*1.0)/(x-pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0])
print self.slope
```

is pretty easy ... the problem really was that you were calling float on the result of the math (which was already an integer)

Comment: Wow, that was a simple fix...Thanks alot, Sadly I probably never would have figured that out...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are converting to float after the result has already been truncated

`float(1/2)` => `float(0)` => `0.0`

You could make sure one of the arguments to `/` is a float. eg.

`1.0/2` => `0.5`

or if you don't want to track down every `/` and make sure one of the arguments is a float (easy to miss one), you can place

```
from __future__ import division
```

as the first line of your file

This makes Python2 behave like Python3 for `/`

If you *need* integer division somewhere, just use `//` (this works the same for Python2 and Python3)

Comment: this is a great answer ... and if you dont want integer division anywhere this is probably the "right" answer +1 (and now +2 if I could with the extra explain :P)